# Compare property/field of a class with (all) other classes

Tags: java

Let's say that I have property/field of a class `Character` that's called `position` which is basically two coordinates:

```
public class Character {
  int[][] position;

  public Character(int[][] position) {
    this.position = position;
  }
}
```

Let's say that I want characters to be able to interact if and only if their position is exactly the same, something like this:

```
public void interact() {
  for character in all_characters {
    if (this.position = character.position) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

How would I get an array of all instantiated objects from that class, i.e. `all_characters` above.

Comment: You'll need to just keep track of your `Characters` yourself by storing them in a list

Comment: You will have to have a controller (to have a good quality) to do that and a use of observer pattern would be also a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not automagically done. You must keep track of entities, possibly decorating them with interfaces to be able to track such things, for example:

```
class Position
{
  private int[][] data;
  public boolean equals(Position other) { .. }
}

interface Positionable
{
  public Position getPosition();
}

class Character implements Positionable
{
  private Position position;
  @Override public Position getPosition() { return position; }
}

class EntityGroup
{
  List<Positionable> entities;

  public Optional<Positionable> findEntityInSamePosition(Positionable p) {
    return entities.stream().filter(p2 -> !p.equals(p2) && p.getPosition().equals(p2.getPosition())).findfirst();

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain/annotate `entityGroup`? Not sure what's going on in there. First you l create a new list that contains all the `positionable` objects? And what happens then?

Comment: It's a collection of all `Character` instances of your program. You need to keep all of them stored somewhere to be able to iterate over them. There is  not an "automatic track of all instances of a specific class" feature.

Comment: So `List<Positionable> entities;` is the collection, right? But what does the method `findEntityInSamePosition` do step by step? (And should its return type be a boolean?) Could you run over the method and explain? How I see it: returns the list of all entities, **what does stream do**?, then filter all the case where **what is the condition between brackets, what's p1 and p2?** and then find the first occurrence, which I suppose means that it'll only return one element with which the position is shared? But doesn't that bypass the point of checking EACH instance?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding getting properties.
It should be available if it's not private.
In java there is a practice to make properties private and implement public getter method for them.
Let me show you an example.

And regarding comparison.

I would suggest try to use `deepEquals` static method of `Arrays` class.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])

```
file Character.java
public class Character {
    private int[][] position;
    public Character(int[][] position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int[][] getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    }

    file Worker.java
    public class Worker {

    List<Character> all_characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

    // all_characters.add(ch1);
    // all_characters.add(ch2);
    // all_characters.add(chN);

    public void interact() {
        for (chLeft in all_characters) {
            for (chRight in all_characters) {
                if(java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(chLeft.getPosition(), chRight.getPosition())) {
                    // Let's interact :)
                }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, applied to my example? I know how to get private variables with getter and setter methods. I'm just unsure how you would apply the deepEquals to my example, considering I am trying to find out if the current object's position is the exact same as any other object of the same class' position.

Comment: Now you have a Class in a Class, right? I was taught that this is very bad practice and shouldn't be done. Is what I was taught wrong? And to better understand this, now you are looping each element twice (once in each loop) isn't that very inefficient? And what's the advantage of `deepEquals` over `=`? I'm sorry for the many questions, just trying to understand instead of copypaste.

Comment: 1. No, it's two public classes - separate java files. 2. It was not clear where you take `this.character` so I wrote method where we goes through all characters and find similar pairs between them. Complexity: `O(n)`. Takes some time. 3. Assume you mean `==` (check equality) but not `=` (apply value on the right to the variable on the left). Difference is the following: `==` will check if objects are referencing to same  object in memory, while `deepEquals` recursively check all values for equality.